# Retrieve data in Python Flask app send by Vue app - Can't read it as JSON

Tags: flask, vuejs2

I'm new to both Flask and Vue.js and I'm a bit confused with everything.

So far, I've created a Flask app that sends data to Vue app, a table with filtering options.
I now want to do the opposite, send filtered data from Vue and store them in a python object.

[image: Architecture of the project]

Here is my simplified code :

**app.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*":{'origins':"*"}})

# Sending data to http://localhost:5000/prices
@app.route("/prices", methods=["GET","POST"])
def all_prices():
    dt_items = init_data()
    json_items = prepare_data_for_front(dt_items)
    return jsonify({"items" : json_items})

# Retrieve data from http://localhost:8085/saved 
@app.route("/saved", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def all_select():
    dt_saved = request.values
    return jsonify(dt_saved)

app.run()
```

Script in **PricesComponent.vue**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
...
methods: {
    async postItems() {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/saved", JSON.stringify(this.filteredTable))
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    },
...
}
```

However, when I got to http://localhost:5000/saved, this is empty. There is no error.
Looking at the console.log, I can see that response.data is an object and not a json, maybe the problem is that my flask app can't jsonify it.